# SQL SELECT query - Join and return field from other table with some logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL query that does the following. I have a table `Contact` and a table `ContactTranslations`. I need to select all contacts from table `Contact` and join the table `ContactTranslations` with this logic:

For each contact:

1. If there is a translation on primary language (language id = 1) then return the title from that translation (Title="PrimaryLanguageTitle").
2. If there is no translation on primary language, then return the first translated title for current contact (Title="FirstTitle").
3. If there are no translations then return 'No translation' (Title="No translation").

My tables look like this:

```
Table: Contact
+-----------+--------+
| ContactId | Active |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      1 |
|         2 |      1 |
|         3 |      1 |
+-----------+--------+

Table: ContactTranslation
+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+
| ContactTranslationId | ContactId | LanguageId  |        Title         |
+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+
|                    1 |         1 | 1 (primary) | PrimaryLanguageTitle |
|                    3 |         2 | 2           | FirstTitle           |
+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Contact 1 has primary language translation and it needs to return 'PrimaryLanguageTitle'.

Contact 2 has no primary language translation but it has one other translation so it should return 'FirstTitle'.

Contact 3 has no translations so it should return 'No translation'

Expected results:

```
+-----------+----------------------+--------+
| ContactId |        Title         | Active |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+
|         1 | PrimaryLanguageTitle |      1 |
|         2 | FirstTitle           |      1 |
|         3 | No translation       |      1 |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+
```

I don't have any SQL code except this:

```
SELECT
    Contact.ContactId AS ContactId,
    IsNull(ContactTranslation.Title, 'No translation') AS Title,
    Contact.Active AS Active
FROM
    Contact
LEFT JOIN ContactTranslation
    ON Contact.ContactId = ContactTranslation.ContactId
```

The problem with this code is that if one contact has many translations then it will return all translations for one contact. It won't follow the logic described above.

Comment: You seem to have a working SQL code, what seem to be your issue/question?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the first language provided for each contact's translation

```
SELECT c.contactid,
       ISNULL(title, 'No translation') title,
       active
  FROM contact c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT contactid,
                          languageid,
                          title
                     FROM (SELECT contactid,
                                  languageid,
                                  title,
                                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contactid ORDER BY MIN(languageid)) rmin
                             FROM contacttranslation
                            GROUP BY contactid,
                                     languageid,
                                     title
                          ) t

                    WHERE rmin = 1) t
    ON c.contactid = t.contactid
```

Comment: You can place the WHERE clause to limit the value to specific id in the inner most SELECT. Right after this

    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contactid ORDER BY MIN(languageid)) rmin
                                 FROM contacttranslation

Answer (score 0):

Do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT
    Contact.ContactId AS ContactId,
    IsNull(ContactTranslation.Title, 'No translation') AS Title,
    Contact.Active AS Active
FROM
    Contact
FULL JOIN ContactTranslation
    ON Contact.ContactId = ContactTranslation.ContactId
```

Comment: It doesn't follow the logic. If there is no primary translation, return the first one. If there is no first then return 'no translation'.